# How to do proper error handling with async/await

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, error-handling, promise

I'm writing an API where I'm having a bit of trouble with the error handling. What I'm unsure about is whether the first code snippet is sufficient or if I should mix it with promises as in the second code snippet. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
try {
  var decoded = jwt.verify(req.params.token, config.keys.secret);
  var user = await models.user.findById(decoded.userId);
  user.active = true;
  await user.save();
  res.status(201).json({user, 'stuff': decoded.jti});
} catch (error) {
  next(error);
}
```

Second code snippet:

```
try {
      var decoded = jwt.verify(req.params.token, config.keys.secret);
      var user = models.user.findById(decoded.userId).then(() => {

      }).catch((error) => {

      });
      user.active = true;
      await user.save().then(() => {

      }).catch((error) => {

      })
      res.status(201).json({user, 'stuff': decoded.jti});
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
```

Comment: First one looks completely fine.

Comment: I read some articles that suggested the need of a try/catch block for each request.. Is there any truth to that?

Comment: It depends. 
Yes if: Do you want to react differently after every async call? (e.g. different response for every erroneous case)
No if: Do you want to proceed with responding back only if all async calls are resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: *it depends*.

**Catch every error**

Makes sense if you want to *react* differently on every error.
e.g.:

```
 try {
        let decoded;
        try {
          decoded = jwt.verify(req.params.token, config.keys.secret);
        } catch (error) {
          return response
            .status(401)
            .json({ error: 'Unauthorized..' });
        }
...
```

However, the code can get quite messy, and you'd want to split the error handling a bit differently (e.g.: do the JWT validation on some *pre request* hook and allow only valid requests to the *handlers* and/or do the `findById` and `save` part in a *service*, and throw once per operation).

You might want to throw a 404 if no entity was found with the given ID.

**Catch all at once**

If you want to react in the *same* way if *a)* or *b)* or *c)* goes wrong, then the first example looks just fine.

```
  a) var decoded = jwt.verify(req.params.token, config.keys.secret);
  b) var user = await models.user.findById(decoded.userId);
  user.active = true;
  c) await user.save();
  res.status(201).json({user, 'stuff': decoded.jti});
```

Answer (score 0):

> I read some articles that suggested the need of a try/catch block for each request. Is there any truth to that?

No, that is not required.  `try/catch` with `await` works conceptually like `try/catch` works with regular synchronous exceptions.  If you just want to handle all errors in one place and want all your code to just abort to one error handler no matter where the error occurs and don't need to catch one specific error so you can do something special for that particular error, then a single `try/catch` is all you need.

But, if you need to handle one particular error specifically, perhaps even allowing the rest of the code to continue, then you may need a more local error handler which can be either a local `try/catch` or a `.catch()` on the local asynchronous operation that returns a promise.

> or if I should mix it with promises as in the second code snippet.

The phrasing of this suggests that you may not quite understand what is going on with `await` because promises are involved in both your code blocks.

In both your code blocks `models.user.findById(decoded.userId);` returns a promise.  You have two ways you can use that promise.

1. You can use `await` with it to "pause" the internal execution of the function until that promise resolves or rejects.
2. You can use `.then()` or `.catch()` to see when the promise resolves or rejects.

Both are using the promise returns from your `models.user.findById(decoded.userId);` function call.  So, your phrasing would have been better to say "or if I should use a local `.catch()` handler on a specific promise rather than catching all the rejections in one place.

---

Doing this:

```
// skip second async operation if there's an error in the first one
async function someFunc() {

    try {
        let a = await someFunc():
        let b = await someFunc2(a);
        return b + something;
    } catch(e) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Is analogous to chaining your promise with one `.catch()` handler at the end:

```
// skip second async operation if there's an error in the first one
function someFunc() {
    return someFunc().then(someFunc2).catch(e => "");
}
```

No matter which async function rejects, the same error handler is applied.  If the first one rejects, the second one is not executed as flow goes directly  to the error handler.  This is perfectly fine IF that's how you want the flow to go when there's an error in the first asynchronous operation.

But, suppose you wanted an error in the first function to be turned into a default value so that the second asynchronous operation is always executed.  Then, this flow of control would not be able to accomplish that.  Instead, you'd have to capture the first error right at the source so you could supply the default value and continue processing with the second asynchronous operation:

```
// always run second async operation, supply default value if error in the first
async function someFunc() {

    let a;
    try {
        a = await someFunc():
    } catch(e) {
        a = myDefaultValue;
    }
    try {
        let b = await someFunc2(a);
        return b + something;
    } catch(e) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Is analogous to chaining your promise with one `.catch()` handler at the end:

```
// always run second async operation, supply default value if error in the first
function someFunc() {
    return someFunc()
      .catch(err => myDefaultValue)
      .then(someFunc2)
      .catch(e => "");
}
```

Note: This is an example that never rejects the promise that `someFunc()` returns, but rather supplies a default value (empty string in this example) rather than reject to show you the different ways of handling errors in this function.  That is certainly not required.  In many cases, just returning the rejected promise is the right thing and that caller can then decide what to do with the rejection error.